# Qt QML Unsupported Image Format for SVG Files

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml, embedded-linux, qtembedded

I am continually getting the errors below when launching a Qt Embedded application that uses QML. From Googling around it seems like I needed to add the image loading plugins to my embedded system's exported nfs. So I attempted to add them several places but I keep getting the errors. I added the embedded ARM's version of libqsvg.so to the following locations but still get the errors...

```
/home/user/exported-nfs/lib/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so
/home/user/exported-nfs/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so
/home/user/exported-nfs/usr/bin/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so
/home/user/exported-nfs/usr/lib/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so
/home/user/exported-nfs/usr/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so
```

This doesn't work either:

```
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/plugins:/usr/plugins/imageformats
echo $QT_PLUGIN_PATH
```

How can I fix this?? Where is the proper place that I need to put the plugins so they are found?

The errors:

> WARNING:
>   file:///usr/share/maliit/plugins/org/nemomobile/FunctionKey.qml:98:5:
>   QML Image: Error decoding:
>   file:///usr/share/maliit/plugins/org/nemomobile/icon-m-input-methods-backspace.svg:
>   Unsupported image format
>   WARNING:
>   file:///usr/share/maliit/plugins/org/nemomobile/FunctionKey.qml:98:5:
>   QML Image: Error decoding:
>   file:///usr/share/maliit/plugins/org/nemomobile/icon-m-input-methods-shift-lowercase.svg:
>   Unsupported image format
>   WARNING:
>   file:///usr/share/maliit/plugins/org/nemomobile/FunctionKey.qml:98:5:
>   QML Image: Error decoding:
>   file:///usr/share/maliit/plugins/org/nemomobile/icon-m-input-methods-backspace.svg:
>   Unsupported image format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to copy the plugins directory to my embedded board at the location specified by the -plugins flag in the configure step.. In my case /usr/lib/qt/plugins. You can also set the environment variable QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS to 1 to get some debug output from any plugins that fail to load.